# Widget Form Multiselect - Default Value

Tags: forms, widgets, default

I've checked `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Multiselect` and I don't see any support for such a thing, but I thought I'd ask my peers: Is there any built-in way to provide a default value to a Widget Form multiselect?

I have a store selector, and I want *All Store Views* to be selected by default. I know that I could set `store_id` to have a default of `0` in my database table, but the UI still asks the user to select a value when first creating an entry.

Answer (score 1):

After you define the form try adding this :

```
$form->addValues(array('store_id' => 0));
```